# What is the clearest way to say you have three bowls each containing rice, egg and veggies, respectively?

Tags: phrase-request, conjunctions

It is not like each bowl contains all three things. It is like the first bowl contains egg, second bowl veggies, and third bowl rice.

I don't want to say it all separately. Can I say it like I did in the title?

Comment: *Three bowls, each containing rice, egg **or** veggies.*

Comment: Do you have three bowls in total or 12 bowls?

Comment: **each** and **respectively** do not pair well together, as their meaning is pretty much opposite.  *Three bowls each containing rice, eggs, and veggies* (all three bowls contain these *combined* ingredients) versus *"Three bowls containing rice, eggs, and veggies, respectively* (one bowl has rice, one has eggs, and one has veggies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> three bowls each containing rice, egg and veggies, respectively

In *each X of Y* or *X { [that] | for } each {verb} Y*, X and Y have to be one thing.  No "splitting" like you are trying to do will work.

So don't use *each*:

> I have three bowls that respectively contain rice, egg, and veggies.

This, while correct can catch a listener or reader off guard.  Adding *then* in this way will drive home the point that you mean three separate bowls a little better.

> I have three bowls that respectively contain rice, egg, and then veggies.

Answer (score 0):

I have three bowls: one containing rice, one containing eggs and one containing veggies.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of why this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.